# R parallel method mclapply seems do not work on Linux

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have tried some method to test parallel computation performance of R. But I face some problems. Following script documents my test codes.

```
rm(list = ls())
##setwd("/Users/chendongwang/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/Learn_Chendong/ModelCode_Chendong/R_Notes")
library(data.table)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse)) # including ggplot2, stringr, dplyr and etc.
library(fixest)  # Fast and user-friendly fixed-effects estimation to perform estimations with multiple fixed-effects in both an OLS and a GLM context
library(Matrix) # matrix operation
library(boot)  # do bootstrap
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)


# generate data set ####
set.seed(45)
n <- 1500000
x1 <- rnorm(n)
x2 <- rnorm(n)
y <- x1 + 2*x2 + rnorm(n)
dt <- data.table(y, x1, x2)
# Define function to compute regression coefficients
regression <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,]
  coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = d))
}

rm(n, x1, x2, y)

# simple boot() ####
cat("Sequential Computing:", sep = "\n")
set.seed(45)
system.time(
  boot_regression1 <- boot(data = dt, statistic = regression, 
                           R = 500, parallel = "no")
)
quantile(boot_regression1$t[, 2], c(0.025, 0.975))


# boot() Parallel Computing. Only on MacOS ####
cat("Parallel Computing, boot():", sep = "\n")
set.seed(45)
system.time(
  boot_regression2 <- boot(data = dt, statistic = regression, 
                           R = 500,  parallel = "multicore", ncpus = 30)
)
quantile(boot_regression2$t[, 2], c(0.025, 0.975))



# mclapply() ####
cat("Parallel Computing, mclapply():", sep = "\n")
set.seed(45)
system.time(
  boot_regression3 <- mclapply(1:500, function(i) {
    # I use dplyr::slice_sample
    xnew <- slice_sample(dt, n = nrow(dt), replace = TRUE)
    coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = xnew))
  }, mc.cores = 30)
)

bad <- sapply(boot_regression3, inherits, what = "try-error")
unique(bad)

# Collapse list into vector, then to matrix.
boot_regression3 <- data.table(matrix(unlist(boot_regression3), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
quantile(boot_regression3$V2, c(0.025, 0.975))


# Socket Cluster ####
cat("Parallel Computing, Socket Cluster:", sep = "\n")
set.seed(45)
cl <- makeCluster(30)  #  default is a socket cluster

# Export data to child processors
clusterExport(cl, c("dt"))

# Export package to child processors
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(dplyr)
  library(data.table)
  library(fixest)
  library(Matrix)
})

system.time({
  boot_regression4 <- parLapply(cl, 1:500, function(i) {
    xnew <- slice_sample(dt, n = nrow(dt), replace = TRUE)
    coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = xnew))
  })
})

# Collapse list into vector, then to matrix.
boot_regression4 <- data.table(matrix(unlist(boot_regression4), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))
quantile(boot_regression4$V2, c(0.025, 0.975))

stopCluster(cl)
```

I have test the aforementioned code on Mac and Linux, but I get some confused problems.

On Mac, four methods run well (68s, 85s, 44s, 29s), but the second result (i.e. multicore in boot) seems do not work. The last method (i.e. socket cluster) really works.

But on Linux, time cost are 71s, 91s, 93s, 23s respectively. The third method (i.e. mclapply) does not bring efficiency.

So, my question are:

1. why multicore mode has higher time cost?
2. why mclapply seems do not work on Linux?

I will provide anything else like env information if you need. Thank you first.